BJT transistors using diodes?
I am researching about Bipolar Junction Transistors and found this image on website: Circuit Crush - How a BJT Works, figure 4:



I know that this configuration of diodes is not correct due to the way how diodes work, and yet there seems to be a handful of websites that uses this configuration. Can someone explain in more detail why this might not work.

This is an oversimplified model. On their own, both the base-collector junction and the base-emitter junction act as diodes, but together they act as a transistor. You can't just stick two diodes together and get them to work as a transistor.

Can you explain in more detail why?

That symbol represents the simplified physical structure of the actual silicon materials used for npn (or pnp) transistors. It is there at the beginning to help explain the names and how the BE junction must be biased so the transistor must work.

Jadon : An important point not usually mentioned is when the transistor is conducting there is an effective diode / virtual diode / conduction path from collector to emitter that does not match the current paths shown by the diodes. You don't need to be overly concerned with that at this point except to realise that when the simplistic diode model doesn't make sense it is because it is far from a complete model.

@RussellMcMahon the "conduction path from conductor to emitter" is a lie told to children. It may allow one to reason about transistor behavior, but no such pathway physically exists. Thus, this model needs to be unlearned at some point. All of the current between emitter and collector passes through the base.

@MathKeepsMeBusy  "Sabres at dawn!" :-). || As I said: "effective diode / virtual diode" ... --> How it gets where it goes is a level or few down. | This "lie" is especially useful in saturation when Vce is lower than Vbe. Current then flows from collector to emitter "via the base" (uphill both ways , cardboard box, lake, ...) via apparently the now (apparently) forward biased CB "diode". Explanations that are both simple and very very hard to arrive at for beginners. Noting that there is a real path from C to E (whether it goes via B) is more helpful than deeper delving. I suggest. No?

@MathKeepsMeBusy In the unlikely event that the "uphill both ways" reference was not clear here is the grainy black and white poor quality original. :-)

@MathKeepsMeBusy  Take 3 :-) - If you can suggest a simple for beginners expalnation that is not lies and covers necessary truth it would be welcome. I'm not going to attempt that in the immediate future. 0315 am and I should be asleep. (He says every night :-) )

The double diode representation fails to describe the geometry of the system. There are indeed two PN junctions (diodes) in a BJT, but those junctions share the same P-type (for NPN) or N-type (for PNP) central layer (the base), and that layer is very thin.
In isolation, the two junctions behave as any PN junction would, blocking current in one direction while permitting current flow in the other, but the physical close proximity (due to small base thickness) of holes/electrons entering the base region across one of those junctions permits them to interact with the other junction in a way that would not be possible for two back-to-back diodes separated by a length of wire.
For example, in an NPN transistor, electrons emerging from the emitter into the base region could recombine with holes there to form base-emitter current in the usual diode-like way, but there is a much greater probability that they get "swept" straight into the nearby base-collector junction's depletion region, where they contribute to current flow via the collector instead, giving rise to the 1:β base:collector current ratio (gain) you would expect from a BJT.
That's only possible if the base region is very thin, which is not the case for back-to-back diodes whose junctions do not share a common "N" or "P" region between them, and which are physically distant.

Good answer. In addition, only the emitter is heavily doped, while the base is lightly doped. That means that there can be a large concentration of free electrons in the (thin) base region of an NPN transistor. In contrast, in a standard diode, electrons in the anode rapidly recombine with holes, so the concentration of free electrons in the anode is much smaller.

There's a very good picture of a 2n2222 at wikipedia and another at Mialhe et al 2008 but I'm not sure how they match the "sandwich" diagram we always see.

Simon: Please se my comment on the question re collector-emitter conduction. This is hopefully another way of saying what you say but (hopefully) even more simply. If you think it misleads polease advise and I'll modify or remove it.

@RussellMcMahon If anyone needs enlighteneing, it's me. I have never fully understood the mechanism of the BJT, except in the terms used in all undergrad courses, and I'm not sure I believe them, ultimately. If asked, I couldn't explain why electrons (for NPN) travelling from emitter to collector don't require 0.7eV to cross the B-E junction ($V_{CE}=0.1V$), as do electrons participating in base current....

@RussellMcMahon I once asked this question because I feel utterly unqualified to talk about BJTs except in a circuit (engineering) setting, not a physics one. Consequently, I would gladly defer to an expert (yourself, perhaps) for a better explanation, if the one I gave is too "hand wavy".

@RussellMcMahon I have no reason to doubt you, whatever you add can only improve my argument of "by proximity". Personally I wonder if the transport of an electron across two potential barriers isn't actually a quantum tunneling event facilitated somehow by base current. No doubt that's ridiculous, but it's more appealing to me than the classical explanation, which I clearly don't fully grok.

I was trying to quantify "very thin": apparently (2n2222) the emitter is on top and a few hundred nanometres thick, the base is a micron or so, and the collector is half a millimetre.  In the microscope photos we see metal layers with roughly hand-shaped E in centre, surrounded by B, all sitting on top of C.  Says professor in excellent explanation of a splendidly-amateur video.

Simon Fitch's answer is fine. However, Russell McMahon asked if I could suggest a simple explanation of transistor action that is accurate. Simple and accurate are perhaps conflicting goals. But here is an attempted compromise.
The dominant carriers in an NPN transistor are free electrons. This is true for the emitter and collector (where they are called majority carriers) and in the base (where they are called minority carriers).
An NPN transistor typically quite asymmetric in it's construction. The emitter is highly doped compared to the base and collector. The concentration of free electrons in the emitter is naturally quite high.
Although the free electrons in the transistor are mostly traveling randomly, there may be a small average movement of free electrons in one direction or another that we call electron current. This is analogous to how molecules in the air are mostly traveling randomly, although there might be a small average movement in one direction or another that we call wind.
Note that the theory of electricity predated the discovery of electrons, and what we now call "conventional current", was arbitrarily defined to be flowing in the opposite direction to an actual flow of electrons. However, in this answer, we will focus on electron current.
Electric fields tend to cause electron current to flow toward a positive potential. This tendency is called drift. Random motion tends to cause electrons to diffuse from areas with a high concentration of electrons to areas with lower concentrations. Sometimes these two tendencies work in unison. Sometimes these two tendencies work in opposition.
The base of a transistor is very thin, so free electrons in an NPN transistor easily diffuse through the base, resulting in many electrons arriving at the border of the base-collector junction. If the potential in the collector is more positive than in the base, most of the free electrons that reach the base-collector junction will be swept across that junction and from there flow to the collector terminal and leave the transistor.
Those free electrons that enter the base from the emitter, but do not cross over into the collector form electron current that flows out of the base terminal. In terms of conventional current, they "make" conventional current that flows into the base.
We have considered the case where the collector is more positive than the base. In that case, electrons move from a less positive region to a more positive region. However, when the collector is less positive than the base, many electrons still move from base to collector. This is because the base has a higher concentration of electrons than the collector. So, electrons will diffuse from the base to the collector. Of course some electrons will move from collector to base, i.e. toward the more positive region. This tendency will be stronger the less positive the collector is. However, unless the collector potential is very nearly equal to the emitter potential, the tendency to diffuse from base to collector will be stronger than the tendency to move in the opposite direction due to base being more positive than the collector.
It should be noted that the ratio of the number of electrons leaving the base via the collector, vs the number of electrons leaving the base via the base terminal is known as beta or \$\beta\$. When the base is more positive than the collector, the net rate of electrons leaving the base via the collector is less than when the collector is more positive. That is, beta is smaller. This condition where the base is more positive than the collector is known as saturation.
This explanation of transistor action obscured some of the details. For example discussion of holes in NPN transistor is neglected. There is no discussion of built-in potentials at junctions. There is a lot more that can be said. However, I believe this outline to be both accurate in its essentials, and comprehensible to a novice.
